# why is my function returning HTML file instead of error/json?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When my login function encounters an error, such as when the email or password is missing, or when the student does not exist or their email is not verified, the response from the server is in HTML format instead of JSON. This HTML response includes an error message along with a stack trace, which is not suitable for consumption by frontend applications expecting JSON responses.

```
const asyncHandler = (requestHandler) => {
    return (req,res,next) => {
        Promise.resolve(requestHandler(req,res,next)). 
        catch((err)=>next(err))
    }
}

export {asyncHandler}
```

the ApiError class to throw custom error messages

```
class ApiError extends Error{
    constructor(
        statusCode,
        message = "Something went wrong",
        errors = [],
        stack = ""
    ){
        super(message)
        this.statusCode = statusCode
        this.data = null,
        this.message = message 
        this.success = false
        this.errors = errors

        if(stack){
            this.stack = stack
        }
        else{
            Error.captureStackTrace(this,this.constructor)
        }

    }
}

export {ApiError}
```

login function, it works fine but not when in error handling

```
const login = asyncHandler(async(req,res) => {

    const {Email, Password} = req.body;

    /*if(!Email){
        throw new ApiError(400,"E-mail is required")
    }
    if(!Password){
        throw new ApiError(400,"Password is required")
    }*/

    const result = await authSchema.validateAsync(req.body)

    const StdLogin = await student.findOne({
        Email
    })

    if(!StdLogin){
        throw new ApiError(400, "Student does not exist")
    }

    if(!StdLogin.Isverified){
        throw new ApiError(401, "Email is not verified");
    }

    const StdPassCheck = await StdLogin.isPasswordCorrect(Password)

    if(!StdPassCheck){
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Password is incorrect" });
    }

    const tempStd = StdLogin._id

    
    const {Accesstoken, Refreshtoken} =  await generateAccessAndRefreshTokens(tempStd)

    const loggedInStd = await student.findById(tempStd).select(-Password -Refreshtoken)

    const options = {
        httpOnly:true,
        secure:true,
    }

    return res
    .status(200)
    .cookie("Accesstoken", Accesstoken, options)
    .cookie("Refreshtoken", Refreshtoken, options)
    .json(
        new ApiResponse(
            200,{
            user:loggedInStd
            }, "logged in"
            )
    )

})
```

RESPONSE I AM GETTING INCASE OF ERROR:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Error: Student does not exist<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at file:///C:/parag/CollegeProject/e-Learning-Platform/backend/src/controllers/student.controller.js:133:15<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the function to return error or json data incase of error

Comment: Question is: why did you write an apierror module that throws http errors? You can’t have a json response if you make the server error out. Throwing an http error should be done when a request cannot be processed for some reason. For example, you can throw an 404 http response if a file doesn’t exist on the server. Since there is no file that can be served, nothing is sent back except an http response of 404 Not Found and (in most cases) some html stating the same “404 error”.

Comment: But since you want to have json as response, you should handle it as status 200 Found, since that is what happened. Technically, the request was processed normally, everything went fine, so you should send back a 200 response.

Answer (score 0):

**`await` throws?**

If either `const result = await authSchema.validateAsync...` or `await student.findOne...` throws, the inline handler function throws and hence rejects its returned promise, which causes

```
Promise.resolve(requestHandler(req,res,next))
```

in `asyncHandler` to reject which is caught and handled in `asyncHandler` by calling `next(err)`. In express at least, `next(err)` invokes an in-built error handler that responds to the request with an HTML page formatted as described in the post.

The issue is consistent with `next(err)` being called, which is consistent with one of the `await` statements throwing without being caught (before the `APIError` Error extension is even used in runtime code).

**TL;DR**

Solutions could be to add `try/catch` statements around `await` statements that are capable of throwing and explicitly handle errors in a controlled manner, or by using `APIError` to create a consumable response instead of calling `next(err)` within `asyncHandler`.

Disclaimer: this answer has not reviewed the design or use of `APIError` in any way.

Answer (score 0):

When your app throw an Error, if you don't have any middleware to handle and return a json following res object, nodejs will return a html.
[image]

You need a middleware like this:

```js
const returnError = (err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  let error;
  if (err instanceof ApiError) {
    error = {};
    error.data = err.data;
    error.statusCode = err.statusCode;
    error.message = err.message;
    error.errors = err.errors;
    error.success = err.success;
  } 
  return res.status(statusCode).json({
    success: error.success !== undefined ? error.success : false,
    status: statusCode,
    message: error.message || 'Internal server error',
    errors: error.errors || [],
    data: error.data
  });
};
```

In app.js or index.js

```js
app.use(returnError);
```

The result:
[image]